# Regular Expression inside a MySQL Like value

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Reg ex again.

Trying to run a like SQL query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * From tablename WHERE somthing LIKE '%id|length:3:\"{$id}\"%'");
```

problem is the length value will be unknown, only the ID.

Of course, I could use strlen($id) and do this:

```
$len = intval(strlen($id));
mysql_query("SELECT * From tablename WHERE somthing LIKE '%id|length:{$len}:\"{$id}\"%'");
```

But I dont really care to check the len value, there's gotta be a bit of Reg ex to match anything where the length will be and sort this without having to calc the length before.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * From tablename WHERE somthing LIKE '%id|length:^*:\"{$id}\"%'");
```

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Naddiseo's link is a good one, I recommend you use `REGEXP`. What do you mean by 'No exact example matching'?

Try something like (I added in the newlines for readability):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * From tablename 
             WHERE somthing 
             REGEXP '^.*id\\\|length:[0-9]+:\"{$id}\".*$'");
```

The relevant regex without worrying about escaping for MYSQL/php strings is

```
^.*id\|length:[0-9]+:"abc".*$
```

(assuming `abc` is a particular ${id}).

It says, "look for anything followed by the *literal* string `id|length:` (I've escaped it as `|` has a special meaning in regex and you want literal `|`), followed by numbers (`[0-9]+`) being the length of the id, followed by `:"{$id}"` and anything else (where `{$id}` has been substituted in).

Now, if you read the [MySQL regexp page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) that @Naddiseo quoted, you'd see that any backslashes need to be further escaped as MySQL parses backslashes as special characters.

So, if you were to enter this query into a MySQL command line (let's assume `{$id}` is `abc` for now), you'd have to type:

```
SELECT * From tablename 
  WHERE somthing 
  REGEXP '^.*id\\|length:[0-9]+:"abc".*$'
```

Now, since you are calling this from PHP inside double quotes, you need to escape your backslashes *again* to make sure the right number get through to MySQL, as well as backslashing your double quotes to escape them. Hence the three backslashes in the `mysql_query` above before the `|`.